# Python Flask error logging - possible to pickle objects which threw error?

Tags: python, flask

I am learning about Flask's error logging and I am wondering if it is possible to pickle the object / objects that caused the error to make it easier to debug.  The Flask documentation suggests that more info on errors is better, but why can't you just pickle the objects to make for easy debugging later?

Comment: Not all objects are pickleable. What do you do with the unpickleable ones?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go as far as recommending that you log all the objects because, depending on your scenario, you could end up logging sensitive data in a file or some other medium that could be the target of some data thief. If this is just for testing then my comment is irrelevant.
To do what you want, you could create a `logging.Filter`-derived class and add it to the logger:

`python
app.logger.addFilter(MyCustomFilter())`

Your filter, `MyCustomFilter` could look for objects in the thread local data and pickle each one into the `record` received in its `filter` method. These object would have been put there by you, in the thread local data.

```
# somewhere in your code, when you decide an object needs to be logged in case of error
local_data = threading.local()
if getattr(local_data, 'objects_to_log', None) is None:
    local_data.objects_to_log = [ ]
local_data.objects_to_log.append(my_object_to_be_logged)

#in MyCustomFilter:
def filter(self, record):
    local_data = threading.local()
    if getattr(local_data, 'objects_to_log', None) is not None:
        for obj in local_data.objects_to_log:
            # todo: pickle each object and add to record
```

I realize this is not a complete and ready to use solution, but it could give you something to work with.